# C++ base class pointer container, edit attributes of specific object

Tags: c++, class, pointers, containers, radix

I have a base class of animal and derived classes called Cat and Dog. display() and readfile() are both virtual functions in both classes.

Currently, only "Kay" is displayed on screen once readfile() is called. How can I read all the lines in the file in a way so that I can find a item in the vector and then later edit it so for example if I want to change "Sugar" to "Sopa" by running a function called changeName() for example?

```
Cat.csv
Kay
Sugar
Jo 


int main() 
{
   AnimalCollection coll;

   std::ifstream file("Cat.csv");

   Cat *cat = new Cat("CAT");
   Dog *dog = new Dog("DOG");

   coll.push_back(cat);
   coll.push_back(dog);

  for (Animal *c : coll)
  {
     c->display();
  }

  for (Animal *c : coll)
  {
    c->readfile(file);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Load the contents of the file into an appropriate container (i.e. `std::map`) and retrieve the information from the container when it's required.

Comment: What you describe does not correspond to the code you posted, however something that is consistent between the two is that you are asking a single animal to read the file, and expecting multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

This question is missing an important part.

Like @KennyOstrom pointed out the file seems to be read just once.
A `file.seekg(0, file.beg);` can help.

Is this solving your problems?

```
for (Animal *c : coll)
{
   c->readfile(file);
   file.seekg(0, file.beg);
}
```

In this case a better solution would be to read the file once and give the  content to the different class.